# Django. Опять статические файлы

Tags: django

Здравствуйте.
Думаю у многих возникала данная проблема, но она была решаема пока работа велась локально. После загрузки на хостинг файлы не подгружаются. Пути все изменил.

Вот весь код для работы:

settings.py:

```
...
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/freethin/projects/items/items/static/',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
...
```

urls.py:

```
...
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

index.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
        <link href="{% static 'style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static 'bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Кстати Debug у меня True, но где-то читал, что он должен быть отключён на сервере.
Пробовал отключать, получаю 400 ошибку вроде. Да и дописывать хотел уже на хостинге.

Спасибо за советы заранее.

**UPD:**

```
В STATIC_ROOT добавил путь из STATIC_DIRS = '/home/freethin/projects/items/items/static/'.
```

Запускал команду на сервере - python manage.py collectstatic. Вот трейсбек -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dictconfig.py", line 553, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/dictconfig.py", line 339, in configure
    'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse
```

**UPD 2:**

Информация:

```
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   3200.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   2128.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   2128.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   2128.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   2128.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   2128.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   3200.000
Processor Name  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31230 @ 3.20GHz
Vendor ID   GenuineIntel
Processor Speed (MHz)   2128.000
Total Memory    8147568 kB
Free Memory 183836 kB
Total Swap Memory   0 kB
Free Swap Memory    0 kB
System Uptime   30 Days, 9 Hours and 49 Minutes
Apache 2.2.24   Running
DirectAdmin 1.42.1  Running
Exim 4.76   Running
MySQL 5.5.30    Running
Named 9.8.2rc1  Running
ProFTPd 1.3.4b  Running
sshd    Running
dovecot 2.1.15  Running
Php 5.3.26  Installed
```

[image]

Comment: ./manage collectstatic делали? STATIC_ROOT должен указывать на каталог откуда ваш сервер сможет отдавать статику.

Comment: обновил вопрос

Comment: Думаю для того что бы кто то посоветовал что то дельное надо привести полную конфигурацию вашего сервера. Кстати вы используете virtualenv или глобально установленный питон и джангу?

Comment: судя по этим "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages" префиксам в путях у вас подхватывается именно глобально установленная джанга. А под конфигурацией сервера я имею ввиду информацию о том что у вас за сервер (nginx, apache или какой-то другой) и как он настроен. Может он статику ищет в другом каталоге.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как это можно проверить или как вызывать именно то, что требуется ) спасибо. просто до публикации дошёл в первый раз, а локально таких проблем не возникало.

Comment: насколько я понял у вас apache, вероятно в связке с mod_wsgi. Как настроить mod_wsgi для virtualenv описано тут - https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments посмотрите.